# Method calls in one rake file task being handled by methods of same name in another rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Using Rails 2.3.*

Say I have a method called some_method() in two rake files - A.rake and B.rake. 
I'm finding that if I call some_method() in B.rake, the method in A.rake is what actually gets called.

So what's the best approach to defining helpers methods inside rake files that will be "local" to the rake task defined in that file?

Thanks

Comment: Example code would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your helper within a task to make it available to that task and all subsequent ones:

```
desc 'has access to local helper'
task :accessible do
  def helper
    return "the helper"
  end

  puts "I have access to #{helper}"
end

desc 'has access too'
task 'after-accessible' => ['accessible'] do
  puts "this ran after 'accessible' but still has access to '#{helper}"
end

desc 'does not have access to the helper'
task :outside do
  puts helper # fails if runs before :accessible
end
```

Perhaps the best thing to do though is to refactor your Rakefiles and the helper code so that the two Rakefiles do not load each other.